# Show by induction that $F_n \geq 2^{0.5 \cdot n}$, for $n \geq 6$

Tags: proof-writing, induction, fibonacci-numbers

I have the following problem:

> Show by induction that $F_n \geq 2^{0.5 \cdot n}$, for $n \geq 6$

Where $F_n$ is the $nth$ Fibonacci number.

---

#### Proof

**Basis**

$n = 6$.

$F_6 = 8 \geq 2^{0.5 \cdot 6} = 2^{\frac{6}{2}} = 2^3 = 8$

**Induction hypothesis**

Assume $F_n \geq 2^{\frac{n}{2}}$, for some $n \geq 6$.

**Inductive step**

Lets shows that $F_{n+1} \geq 2^{\frac{n + 1}{2}}$.

We know that

- $F_{n + 1} = F_n + F_{n - 1}$
- $2^{\frac{n + 1}{2}} > 2^{\frac{n}{2}}$
- $2^{\frac{n + 1}{2}} = 2^{\frac{n}{2} + \frac{1}{2}} = 2^{\frac{n}{2}} \cdot 2^{\frac{1}{2}} \leq 2^{\frac{n}{2}} \cdot 2 = 2^{\frac{n}{2}} + 2^{\frac{n}{2}}$

Since we have assumed that $F_n \geq 2^{\frac{n}{2}}$, then $$F_n + F_{n - 1} = F_{n + 1} \geq 2^{\frac{n}{2}} +  F_{n - 1} \geq 2^{\frac{n}{2}} +  F_{n - 1} + 2^{\frac{n}{2}} - F_n = 2^{\frac{n}{2}} + 2^{\frac{n}{2}} +  F_{n - 1} - F_n$$

The last inequality is true because $2^{\frac{n}{2}} - F_n$ is negative or $0$, since $F_n \geq 2^{\frac{n}{2}}$.

---

I have tried a lot of things, but I cannot figure out how to proceed and how to conclude that indeed $F_{n + 1} \geq 2^{\frac{n}{2}} \cdot 2^{\frac{1}{2}}$. I feel really stupid after trying for a long time to do this alone and not managing to do it.

Comment: You should take as hypothesis that both $F_n\ge2^{n/2}$ and $F_{n+1}\ge2^{(n+1)/2}$. Then show that $F_{n+2}\ge2^{(n+2)/2}$.

Comment: Why not? If you think of it, the reasoning is exactly the same as in the simple case. See also the answers you got and here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_induction.

Answer (score 6):

We have that $F_n>F_{n-1}$ then $$F_{n+1}=F_n+F_{n-1}>2F_{n-1}>2\cdot2^{(n-1)/2}=2^{(n+1)/2}$$

Comment: Ok, but there is a strong induction that you could use.

Comment: You can make like that: Suppose that $f_k\geq 2^{k/2}$ for all $k\leq n$ and then try to prove for $f_{n+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we knew for 2 values of n $F_n \ge 2^{\frac n2}$ i.e for n = 6 and n = 7.

We know this holds for n=6 and n=7.

We also know that $F_{n+1} = F_{n} + F_{n-1}$

So we assume for some k and k-1 (7 and 6) $F_{k-1} \ge 2^{\frac {k-1}{2}}$ and $F_{k+1} \ge 2^{\frac {k+1}{2}}$

We know $F_{k} \ge F_{n-1}$

so $F_{k+1} \ge 2 \cdot F_{n-1}$

Using the assumption $F_{k+1} \ge 2 \cdot 2^{\frac {k-1}{2}} = 2^{\frac{k+1}{2}}$ as required.

EDIT: If you want a phrasing in the language of induction (propositional)
 $$P(k) = F_{n} \ge 2^{\frac{n}{2}} \mbox{ & } F_{n-1} \ge 2^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\\$$
We then prove:
$$
P(k+1) = F_{n+1} \ge 2^{\frac{n+1}{2}} \mbox{ & } F_{n} \ge 2^{\frac{n}{2}}$$

Above I proved the second from the first.